# Why withCookie() is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I have ran into the problem of not being able to set cookie with Laravel 5.2, and the problem has been solved after I read [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5). **(So what I need is not a solution but an explanation.)**

In short,

```
return view('welcome')->withCookie(cookie('test', 'test', 45000));
```

This doesn't work, and to make it work, either:

```
 public function index(CookieJar $cookieJar, Request $request)
 {
     if($request->referrer){
        $cookieJar->queue(cookie('referrer', $request->referrer, 45000));
     }

     return view('welcome');
 }
```

Or:

```
$response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response(view('welcome'));
$response->withCookie(cookie('referrer', $request->referrer, 45000));
return $response;
```

What annoys me is that the first code doesn't return any error while it does not set any cookie, so that means it actually do something valid (but not setting the cookie). What it actually does? And why the later 2 solutions work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first option you are not actually including a cookie, but a parameter called 'cookie' that happens to have the value calculated by the function `cookie`. I mean, you are using the function `withXXXX` of a `View`, which creates a parameter called XXXX. In fact, if you include something like

> {{$cookie}}

in your blade view file, you'll get the value generated with the `cookie` function.

**So, that's what it is actually doing: passing a parameter called cookie to the view builder.**

The second works because you are using a cookieJar and that is automatically preserved.

The third works because you are using the withCookie function **NOT** of a `View` but of a `Response`, which actually creates and returns a cookie.

> TL;DR : You must add the cookie to the response, not to the view.